# Windows 10 will not read Ubuntu formatted Flash drive

Tags: windows, flash

it used to be possible to access an FAT 32 Ubuntu (18.04) formatted flash drive in my Win 10 PC.
For some time now, When I plug an Ubuntu formatted USB drive (tried 3 different ones) it is not recognized and the Bluetooth keyboard mouse freezes.
Removing the flash drive situation becomes normal. Tried all the ports.
The Flash drive and the Bluetooth one are in different ports, but it doesn't matter.
I use Nautilus, no option offered.Tried also with Disks and Gparted.

Purchased a brand new Sandisk drive. Here's how it went: Just plug it to the PC - OK. Format in Ubuntu as above, First pug in not recognised by PC, remove and replug Kaspersky message external device should be scanned, scan was clean, drive is recognized. This is repetitive. Mouse and keyboard working normally.

Thanks, tried your CL. All I get is error "Device partition expected, not making filesystem on entire device '/dev/sdc' (use -I to override)"
(drive is 16GB)

Comment: How are you formatting the flash drive? If you are using a command line utility, please copy and past the exact command in your question and format the command as `code`. If you are using a GUI app, edit your question and add details like the name of the app and which options you selected within the app.

Comment: You may find this [question and its answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493262/fat32-formatting?r=SearchResults) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was: Use Gparted to erase the primary partition, re create it and then format. There's a hidden bug somewhere.

Comment: That might be the solution, but you haven't said what it was you did that caused the apparent problem in the first place.  There's not much point in knowing the solution if we don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might have been that the flash drive contained remnants of an ISO image that confused Windows. A simple mkfs.vfat will not automatically clean any ISO signatures. You can tell that this is the case if the drive that you just formatted with the name "STUFF" still appears with the name "Ubuntu_Live" or whatever. gparted takes care of that, but if you prefer non-gui tools, wipefs will probably do the trick.